# MessageBox Powershell will not shown the script output - Active Directory

Tags: powershell

The following powershell script will not show the output in message box

```
$MyADGroups = Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership ($username = Read-Host "Enter the username") | select name
[System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show($MyADGroups, "Information", 0, 64)
```

MessageBox is empty!

Could someone help?

Kind Regards!

Comment: solved - without "select name" - it works!

Comment: Just a FYI; what you need in order for your select to work in this particular case is to expand the desired property; `<code> | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name`